# Fill NaN with distinct known values within the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column that is labeling a location. The table looks like this

| Don't Care | Id | Dont Care |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 123 | x |
| x | nan | x |
| x | nan | x |
| x | 323 | x |
| x | nan | x |

I don't know what the id numbers are and i don't know how many nans inbetween. What I want to do is fill the names with the number above it like this:

| Don't Care | Id | Dont Care |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 123 | x |
| x | 123 | x |
| x | 123 | x |
| x | 323 | x |
| x | 323 | x |

I really not sure whats the most efficient way to do so. I was thinking of making for loop that would check if it was a number that it been repeating and if not then fill else it would grab that number and move on. but it would create it in a list then ill have to convert to a dataframe but that seem inefficient.

Comment: Try `df['Id'] = df['Id'].ffill()`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using a pandas dataframe

then use

```py
df = df.fillna(method="ffill")
```